# What do do with answers that have pre web3 v1.0 code?

Tags: discussion

What do do with answers that have pre web3 v1.0 code?

This has come up in one answer and will come up in others.

e.g. see [How do I know when I've run out of gas programmatically?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/how-do-i-know-when-ive-run-out-of-gas-programmatically/1182?noredirect=1#comment30448_1182)

There are lots of top-rated questions and answers that use pre-web3 v1.0 code that will likely be out of date once web3 v1.0 officially ships.

What should we do about these questions?  I see user @eth has been posting 'please update' on some of them but I couldn't find the meta discussion on this topic so here it is...

Should new answers be provided or should existing answers be updated?  How should we tag these updates?  (e.g. "web3v1.0" official tag as well as "#web3v.10" keyword in the answer?)

Keep in mind the answerers might have moved on and might not be able to properly update the answers - especially in the case of code they might not be able to test the code properly anymore.

Comment: It is unfortunate but very common fact that new version will deprecate old functionality. It has already happened to solidity with throw, old answers that use throw are no longer good practice, and it will happen again for constant.

Perhaps again in the future a new version will deprecate web3 v1.0 in favor of a new and better v2.0. It is a lot of work to go in the past, review and retag old answers appropiately.

Another approach I've seen is some users explictely create new answers for new versions.

Comment: personally i'm in favor of new answers for new questions, clearly labeled e.g. 'updated answer for web3 1.0'.  I'd also favor adding a tag to those questions with 'web3-1.0' to note that it has been updated (and to allow them to be searched for)